# PHP Form not creating .csv file

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Attempting to have a form filled out and generate a separate .csv file each time its submitted. When the form is filled out the page reloads but does not generate a file currently.

I know there are many other ways to do this but I am very new to this and this way I could kind of wrap my head around better than the others.

```php
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    //collect form data
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $customer = $_POST["customer"];
    $reseller = $_POST["reseller"];
    $standardusers = $_POST["standardusers"];
    $ucusers = $_POST["ucusers"];
    $recording = $_POST["recording"];
    $firewall = $_POST["firewall"];

    //check name is set
    if($name ==''){
        $error[] = 'Name is required';
    }

    //check for a valid email address
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
         $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //check customer name is set
    if($customer ==''){
        $error[] = 'Customer Name is required and must match ConnectWise';
    }

    //check reseller name is set
    if($reseller ==''){
        $error[] = 'Reseller Name is required and must match ConnectWise';
    }

    //check standardusers is set
    if($standardusers ==''){
        $error[] = 'Number of users is required';
    }

    //check ucusers is set
    if($ucusers ==''){
        $error[] = 'Number of users is required';
    }

    //if no errors carry on
    if(!isset($error)){

        //# Title of the CSV
        $Content = "Name, Email, Customer, Reseller, Standard Users, UC Users, Call Recording, Firewall\n";

        //set the data of the CSV
        $Content .= "$name, $email, $customer, $reseller, $standardusers, $ucusers, $recording, $firewall\n";

        //# set the file name and create CSV file
        $filename = "formdata-".date("d-m-y-h:i:s").".csv";
        header('Content-Type: application/csv'); 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$FileName.'";');
        echo $Content;
        echo gethostname();
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```

Once the form is submitted it should drop the .csv file to the server and let the user know the form was submitted successfully.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please update your question with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem. Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working successfully

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

  $data = array();

  $data['name'] = $_POST["name"] ?? '';
  $data['email'] = $_POST["email"] ?? '';
  $data['customer'] = $_POST["customer"] ?? '';
  $data['reseller'] = $_POST["reseller"] ?? '';
  $data['standardusers'] = $_POST["standardusers"] ?? '';
  $data['ucusers'] = $_POST["ucusers"] ?? '';
  $data['recording'] = $_POST["recording"] ?? '';
  $data['firewall'] = $_POST["firewall"] ?? '';

  $errors = '';

  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'recording' || $key == 'firewall'){ } //do nothing
    else {
      if (empty($value)) {
        //Field is empty && email
        if ($key == 'email') {
          if(!filter_var($data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $errors .= 'Please enter a valid email address \r\n ';
          }
        } else {
          //Field is empty && !email
          $errors .= $key.' field is required. \r\n ';
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //if no errors carry on
  if(empty($errors)){
    //# Title of the CSV
    $Content = "Name, Email, Customer, Reseller, Standard Users, UC Users, Call Recording, Firewall\n";
    //set the data of the CSV
    // Added '' in each field as a delimiter
    // $Content .= "'".$data['name']."', '".$data['email']."', '".$data['customer']."', '".$data['reseller']."', '".$data['standardusers']."', '".$data['ucusers']."', '".$data['recording']."', '".$data['firewall']."'\n";
    $row = '';

    foreach ($data as $key => $value){
      $row .= $value.","; //Append data to csv
    }
    //Remove trailing comma
    $row = mb_substr($row, 0, -1);

    $Content .= $row;
    //# set the file name and create CSV file
    // $filename = "formdata-".date("d-m-y-h:i:s").".csv";
    // header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    // header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$FileName.'";');
    // echo $Content;
    // echo gethostname();
    // exit();

    $csv_handler = fopen ('csvfile.csv','w');
    if(fwrite ($csv_handler,$Content)){
      echo 'Data saved to csvfile.csv';
    } else {
      echo "File not saved successfully";
    }
    fclose ($csv_handler);


  } else {
    echo $errors;
  }

}


?>
```

I tested using this form, posting to the script

```
<form class="" action="3.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" >
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" >
  <input type="text" name="customer" placeholder="customer" >
  <input type="text" name="reseller" placeholder="reseller" >
  <input type="text" name="standardusers" placeholder="standardusers" >
  <input type="text" name="ucusers" placeholder="ucusers" >
  <input type="text" name="recording" placeholder="recording" >
  <input type="text" name="firewall" placeholder="firewall" >
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This is great. The only issue I see is the options for "recording" and "firewall"  are required and they should not be. How do I exclude those options? Here is how they are set in the form.
`<p><label class="checkbox">Call Recording?<br><input type='checkbox' name='recording' value=''><span class="checkmark"></span></label></p>
<p><label class="checkbox">Firewall?<br><input type='checkbox' name='firewall' value=''><span class="checkmark"></span></label></p>`

Comment: @quigleyvision for non required fields, if you don't want to manually write the if statements in the first foreach loop you could just put N/A inside the fallback assignment ?? 'N/A'

Comment: so something like this before the array? 
`if (isset($_POST['recording'])) {
  $recording = "Yes";
} else {
  $recording = "No";`

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! I did change the file output to include a timestamp so it will create multiple files each time it is filled out.

 `$timestamp = date("Y-m-d_H-i-s"); //$timestamp takes the current time
    $myFile = "new_deployment.".$timestamp.".csv"; // add timestamp to the file name
    $csv_handler = fopen ($myFile,'w');`